# add a date to the dataframe

Tags: r, date, aggregate, average

The data frame is:

```
head(HSC)

       Date    Y1      M1  Location Year Quarter Month
2010-01-04   0.115   0.245 Chicago 2010      Q1    01
2010-01-05   0.111   0.210 Chicago 2010      Q1    01
2010-01-06   0.113   0.185 Chicago 2010      Q1    01
```

Then I get monthly average for Y1 and M1

```
HSCnew<-aggregate(cbind(Y1,M1)~Month+Year,data=HSC,mean)

Month Year     Y1       M1
  01 2010 -0.11935294 -0.04017647
  02 2010 -0.09776471 -0.05600000
  03 2010 -0.06785714  0.01271429
  04 2010 -0.07315789 -0.02457895
```

Both month and year are characters. is there a way to add date to the right, such date=01-01-2010

Comment: you've aggregated it at a month level - how can your new date have a date value - only month and year are possible right? In your first row of the results, the data is agregated for january 2010, date is irrelevant.

Comment: so how could i add a column to HSCnew, such that date= 01/01/2010...01/02/2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the Date column as a Date type with this:

```
HSCnew$Date <- as.Date(paste(HSCnew$Year, HSCnew$Month, '01', sep='/'))
```

or just

```
HSCnew$Date <- paste('01', HSCnew$Month, HSCnew$Year, sep='-')
```

If you want a string in format dd-mm-yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the day of the month is relevant but you could do this:

```
date <- paste(Year, Month, sep = "-")

require(zoo)
as.yearmon(date)
[1] "Jan 2010"
```